# Change if any EditText is in focus

Tags: java, android, focus, android-edittext, onfocus

In my program i use many EditText dynamically created , and i need to call method each time when any of them get changed (lost focus). is it possible to do such thing ?
otherwise how to make on focus lost\change lister for all View ?

Answer (score 1):

you will need to set [View.setOnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener%29) for EditText to listen for focus change .

**For Example:**

```
 View.OnFocusChangeListener editTextFocusChnage=
                                   new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        swich(v.getId()){
         case  Edittext1_id:
           // do your work here..
                break;
         case Edittext2_id:
          // do your work here..
           break;
         case Edittext3_id:
          // do your work here..
           break;   
          .....        

        }
    }
};
```

where Edittext1_id,Edittext2_id,.... is dynamic EditText id's

**EDIT :-**

add  `FocusChangeListener` to EditText's as:

```
    editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(editTextFocusChnage);
    editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(editTextFocusChnage);
    editText3.setOnFocusChangeListener(editTextFocusChnage);
    .....
```

Comment: I really didn't get this , but anyway i added this to my class :
View.OnFocusChangeListener etcl = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() { 
  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Focus changed ",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   GetCount();
  }
 }; 
and it's don't do anything .. what i'am doing wrong?

Comment: i just try if focus changed , don't matter on what view .

Comment: And is it possible to make onFocusChangeListener for all View?
cause i need to call method when each ET lost focus

Comment: @CVS : all View mean? just add setOnFocusChangeListener to View to which you want to listen focus change ,like TextView,Layout,Button,EditText,.. but some View but default is not Focusable then u will need to make it Focusable

Comment: @CVS : to make View focusable u will need to add `android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in View xml for example to make all TextView's focusable